# Docker compose recreates images on CircleCI even though images are up-to-date

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

We have services as docker images that get built, pushed to Dockerhub, and deployed on every new commit by CircleCI. Recently I made changes to not build images if there are no changes, and also the containers should not be recreated/restarted.

When now a new change is pushed, however, the deploy step recreates the images even though the images are "up-to-date". Normally, when images are up-to-date and no `--force-recreate` flag was passed, the containers should not be recreated.

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue either. Everytime I run the deploy script on the server or by running the deploy CI job again, I get `<image> up-to-date` and no recreating. With a new commit, images get recreated.

What could be the reason for Docker Compose to recreate images even though images are up-to-date?

Output with new commit on CI:

```
Total reclaimed space: 0B
Pulling ui         ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling ipfs       ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling repository ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling ui         ... digest: sha256:e22696dbf450784262...
Pulling ui         ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling ipfs       ... digest: sha256:8b2f5b048da2928b73...
Pulling ipfs       ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling repository ... digest: sha256:c269996c2802528b86...
Pulling repository ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling ui         ... done
Pulling s3sync     ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling ipfs       ... done
Pulling repository ... done
Pulling server     ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling s3sync     ... digest: sha256:27f35299ce74d0f7cc...
Pulling s3sync     ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling s3sync     ... done
Pulling server     ... digest: sha256:8e62ae573dbe9c967e...
Pulling server     ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling server     ... done
Pulling monitor    ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling monitor    ... digest: sha256:a647623055fc9336c3...
Pulling monitor    ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling monitor    ... done
Recreating server-latest ... 
Recreating repository-latest ... 
Recreating monitor-latest    ... 
Recreating ui-latest         ... 
Recreating s3-latest         ... 
Recreating ipfs-latest       ... 
Recreating ui-latest         ... done
Recreating monitor-latest    ... done
Recreating server-latest     ... done
Recreating s3-latest         ... done
Recreating repository-latest ... done
Recreating ipfs-latest       ... done
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

on every other run I get as expected:

```
Total reclaimed space: 0B
Pulling s3sync     ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling s3sync     ... digest: sha256:27f35299ce74d0f7cc...
Pulling s3sync     ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling s3sync     ... done
Pulling ipfs       ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling ipfs       ... digest: sha256:8b2f5b048da2928b73...
Pulling ipfs       ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling monitor    ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling ipfs       ... done
Pulling ui         ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling monitor    ... digest: sha256:a647623055fc9336c3...
Pulling monitor    ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling monitor    ... done
Pulling ui         ... digest: sha256:e22696dbf450784262...
Pulling ui         ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling ui         ... done
Pulling server     ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling server     ... digest: sha256:8e62ae573dbe9c967e...
Pulling server     ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling server     ... done
Pulling repository ... pulling from ethereum/source-verify
Pulling repository ... digest: sha256:c269996c2802528b86...
Pulling repository ... status: image is up to date for e...
Pulling repository ... done
s3-latest is up-to-date
ipfs-latest is up-to-date
repository-latest is up-to-date
monitor-latest is up-to-date
ui-latest is up-to-date
server-latest is up-to-date
```

This is the deploy script **deploy.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "staging" ]; then 
    TAG='latest'
    REPO_PATH='/home/gather/staging/'
    SERVER='-J source-verify@komputing.org gather@10.10.42.102'
elif [ "$CIRCLE_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then
    TAG='stable' 
    REPO_PATH='/home/sourcify/production/'
    SERVER='-J source-verify@komputing.org sourcify@10.10.42.7'
else
    echo "Invalid branch $CIRCLE_BRANCH. Check your config.yml"
    exit 1
fi

curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/source-verify/${CIRCLE_BRANCH}/.circleci/ssh.config" > ~/.ssh/config

ssh $SERVER "\
    mkdir -p scripts && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/source-verify/${CIRCLE_BRANCH}/scripts/setup.sh > scripts/setup.sh && chmod +x scripts/setup.sh && chown $USER:$USER ./scripts/setup.sh && \
    REPO_PATH='${REPO_PATH}' CIRCLE_BRANCH='${CIRCLE_BRANCH}' TAG='${TAG}' ./scripts/setup.sh"
```

which calls this **setup.sh**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mkdir -p $REPO_PATH
cd $REPO_PATH

if [[ ! -d sourcify ]]; then
    git clone https://github.com/ethereum/sourcify.git sourcify
    cd sourcify
    git checkout ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
else
    cd sourcify
    git fetch
    git checkout ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
    git reset --hard origin/${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
fi

if [ "${TAG}" == "stable" ]; then
    COMPOSE_COMMAND="COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=${TAG} docker-compose -f ipfs.yaml -f monitor.yaml -f repository.yaml -f s3.yaml -f server.yaml -f ui.yaml -f ui-legacy.yaml"
elif [ "${TAG}" == "latest" ]; then
    COMPOSE_COMMAND="COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=${TAG} docker-compose -f ipfs.yaml -f monitor.yaml -f repository.yaml -f s3.yaml -f server.yaml -f ui.yaml"
else
    COMPOSE_COMMAND="COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=${TAG} docker-compose -f ipfs.yaml -f monitor.yaml -f repository.yaml -f s3.yaml -f server.yaml -f ui.yaml -f localchain.yaml"
fi

TAG=$TAG ./scripts/find_replace.sh
source ./environments/.env
cd environments
docker image prune -f
eval ${COMPOSE_COMMAND} pull
eval COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=1200 ${COMPOSE_COMMAND} up -d
```